# Getting empty cursor when going to another Activity

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

My problem is that when I click on ListView item to show some details in another Activity my app crashes

Logcat :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.DetailsActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3168)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114)
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
   at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
   at com.khalilteache.eventsreminder.DetailsActivity.populateFields(DetailsActivity.java:171)
   at com.khalilteache.eventsreminder.DetailsActivity.onResume(DetailsActivity.java:88)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1259)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6327)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3168) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114)
```

here when I perform item click :

```
ListView events = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    events.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(EventsActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(ReminderDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);

    }
});
```

here is DetailsActivity where the probleme

```
public class DetailsActivity  extends Activity {

    //
    // Dialog Constants
    //
    private static final int DATE_PICKER_DIALOG = 0;
    private static final int TIME_PICKER_DIALOG = 1;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    //
    // Date Format
    //
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "kk:mm";
    public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss";

    private EditText mTitleText;
    private EditText mBodyText;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private Button mTimeButton;
    private Button mConfirmButton;
    private Long mRowId;
    private ReminderDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Calendar mCalendar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDbHelper = new ReminderDbAdapter(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
        mDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_date);
        mTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_time);
        mConfirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);


        mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(KEY_ROWID)
                : null;

        registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();
    }


    private void setRowIdFromIntent() {
        if (mRowId == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(ReminderDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                    : null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mDbHelper.open();
        setRowIdFromIntent();
        populateFields();
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch(id) {
            case DATE_PICKER_DIALOG:
                return showDatePicker();
            case TIME_PICKER_DIALOG:
                return showTimePicker();
        }
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }

    private DatePickerDialog showDatePicker() {


        DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(DetailsActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateDateButtonText();
            }
        }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        return datePicker;
    }

    private TimePickerDialog showTimePicker() {

        TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                updateTimeButtonText();
            }
        }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);

        return timePicker;
    }

    private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() {

        mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_PICKER_DIALOG);
            }
        });


        mTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_PICKER_DIALOG);
            }
        });

        mConfirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this,"ooo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

        });

        updateDateButtonText();
        updateTimeButtonText();
    }

    private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor reminder = mDbHelper.fetchReminder(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(reminder);

            mTitleText.setText(reminder.getString(
                    reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_TITLE)));
            mBodyText.setText(reminder.getString(
                    reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_BODY)));
        }
    }

    private void updateTimeButtonText() {
        // Set the time button text based upon the value from the database
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
        String timeForButton = timeFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());
        mTimeButton.setText(timeForButton);
    }

    private void updateDateButtonText() {
        // Set the date button text based upon the value from the database
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        String dateForButton = dateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());
        mDateButton.setText(dateForButton);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putLong(KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }
}
```

I spent more then 15 hours looking for solution but I fail. every answer will be appreciated thanks.

This is my ReminderDbAdapter

```
public class ReminderDbAdapter {
    //
    // Databsae Related Constants
    //
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "reminders";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_COLORID = "_id_color";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGEID = "_id_image";


    private static final String TAG = "ReminderDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    /**
     * Database creation SQL statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, "
                    + KEY_BODY + " text not null, "
                    + KEY_COLORID + " integer not null, "
                    + KEY_IMAGEID + " integer not null, "
                    + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null);";



    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     *
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public ReminderDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     *
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public ReminderDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new reminder using the title, body and reminder date time provided.
     * If the reminder is  successfully created return the new rowId
     * for that reminder, otherwise return a -1 to indicate failure.
     *
     * @param title the title of the reminder
     * @param body the body of the reminder
     * @param reminderDateTime the date and time the reminder should remind the user
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createReminder(String title, String body, String reminderDateTime, int color_id, int image_id) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        initialValues.put(KEY_COLORID, color_id);
        initialValues.put(KEY_IMAGEID, image_id);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the reminder with the given rowId
     *
     * @param rowId id of reminder to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all reminders in the database
     *
     * @return Cursor over all reminders
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllReminders() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY, KEY_COLORID, KEY_IMAGEID, KEY_DATE_TIME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the reminder that matches the given rowId
     *
     * @param rowId id of reminder to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching reminder, if found
     * @throws SQLException if reminder could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

                mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                                KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_COLORID, KEY_IMAGEID, KEY_DATE_TIME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the reminder using the details provided. The reminder to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title, body and reminder date time
     * values passed in
     *
     * @param rowId id of reminder to update
     * @param title value to set reminder title to
     * @param body value to set reminder body to
     * @param reminderDateTime value to set the reminder time.
     * @return true if the reminder was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateReminder(long rowId, String title, String body, String reminderDateTime, int color_id, int image_id) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        args.put(KEY_COLORID, color_id);
        args.put(KEY_IMAGEID, image_id);
        args.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, reminderDateTime);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated my post please check if you could save my life

Comment: First things first, I would recommend `ReminderDbAdapter` is the class that extends SqliteOpenHelper. I don't see the purpose of the nested class

Comment: But this doesnt mean if i extend `SqliteOpenHelper` my probleme will be fixed because i think the probleme came from DetailsActivity probably

Comment: `mDbHelper.fetchReminder(mRowId);` has returned an empty cursor, no columns... I don't really know what else to tell you other than to drop and recreate the table / verify that table is correct and has data in it

Comment: Yes im using Sqlite Editor on a rooted device to check if table has data in it and i found that table has data but when i use SimpleCursorAdapter it works but cant modify data in bindView but when i use the method below it doesnt work but this method let me modify data

Comment: It works when using SimpleCursorAdapter to populate data to list
`private void populateListViewFromDB() {
        Cursor remindersCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllReminders();
        startManagingCursor(remindersCursor);
        String[] from = new String[]{RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter reminders = 
             new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.reminder_row, remindersCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(reminders);
    }`
but this method doesnt let me modify data in bindView like CustomAdapter does

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need to modify any data inside the adapter when you only use the adapter to display the data from the database. As I've stated, though, your error clearly states you have a cursor of size 0. Also, `startManagingCursor` is deprecated, so I'm not sure why you are using it

Comment: And that code works because you have `fetchAllReminders` while the error is at `fetchReminder`

Comment: Do you know any way to populate data and bindView using SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: A SimpleCursorAdapter binds the views using the `String[] from` and `int[] to`

Comment: So there no way to modify data before populate ' em to listview ?
so the only way to bindView is using CursorAdapter !!!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding what you're trying to ask. You shouldn't need to modify any data located in an Adapter. You can update the database and reload the cursor.

Comment: but there is DateTime in Database i need to format it and get just date (yyyy-MM-dd) and display it in list rows and im doing that in the BindView but cant do the same thing in SimpleCursorAdapter hope you get what i mean

Comment: Okay, now that makes sense... How does this solve the problem that the cursor is empty for the mentioned method? The adapter isn't the problem. Your database or query is

Comment: when im using CursorAdapter to populate data I get emty cursor (as you mentioned) when clicking on listItem to show the data of the clicked item in other Activity (DetailsActivity). but when I use SimpleCursorAdapter ( `String[] from` and `int[] to` ) everything goes right without errors
so CursorAdapter doesnt work for me but I can't modify date without it
and when using SimpleCursorAdapter the Data are shown in DetailsActivity but with this methos I can't modiy data

Comment: The SimpleCursorAdapter works with `fetchReminder(long id)`? The code you put earlier doesn't use that method

Comment: Yes it works with `fetchReminder(long id)` but it would be great if I can use bindView() in SimpleCursorAdapter and stop using CursorAdapter that doesn't work with `fetchReminder(long id)`

Comment: Then extend SimpleCursorAdapter and implement `bindView`...

Comment: It worked my brow thank you so mutch !!!